# django.db.utils.OperationalError| me harian un re favor

Tags: python, mysql, base-de-datos, django, migration

tengo este probrema al hacer el MAKEMIGRATIONS, ya no se que hacer..

#aca les dejo el error completo de la terminal

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\DATOS\djangoproject\tiendaOnline\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Escritorio\DATOS\djangoproject\tiendaOnline\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 91, in handle
    self.check(databases=[database])
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 487, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 36, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1461, in check
    *cls._check_indexes(databases),
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1864, in _check_indexes
    connection.features.supports_covering_indexes
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\features.py", 
line 84, in is_postgresql_11
    return self.connection.pg_version >= 110000
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 354, in pg_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 639, 
in temporary_connection
    with self.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner 
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 284, 
in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 260, 
in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner 
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 243, 
in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__   
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 244, 
in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner 
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 225, 
in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner 
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 203, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect 
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError
```

#aca les dejo mi settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'articuloClientes',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'fauscapo123',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'DATABASE_PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

espero que puedan ayudarme, es muy desesperanzador, y las reglas de poder hacer una pregunta en stackoverflow me obliga a dar mas detalles" dobre esto, asi que nada, explico que lo estoy haciendo con el postgresql.14.4.1, y no se cual podria ser el problema que tengo, lo estoy haciendo a la par que un video en youtube, y no se por que a mi me da este error, ya vi un post de otra persona que tuvo el mismo problema, pero los que le respondieron pusieron soluciones" que no eran al menos para mi caso.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es por la versión de python, tengo el mismo problema yo tengo la 3.10.6, y segun vi por el momento solo soporta python la versión 3.9